# Connection problems in localhost from my android device

Tags: android, localhost

I'm trying to access localhost from my android device. I've tried 192.168.1.5:80 (which is my localhost ip address in my laptop). Both my android device and my laptop are on same gateway.
Can anyone tell me what i've done wrong or is there any firewall that is blocking my localhost from being accessed?
Help me out guys. Thank you in advance.!!

Comment: Try this..Make sure you have turned off your firewall [add a specific rule allowing the incoming connections to the port once you've successfully connected]..Note the IPv4 address: (it should be 192.168.0.x) for some x. Use this as the server IP address, together with the port number, e.g. 192.168.0.7:8080, in your code.

Comment: Easier way to check this is, in browser of your emulator type 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost.

Comment: i'm not sure where the firewall is turned on for me to turn it off, and I have alreadey tried with the ip address @Lal

Comment: I'm talking about the actual android device here..

Comment: Check your windows firewall if you are using a windows pc..

Comment: turn off your windows firewall first. then open browser from your device and in the url type "localhost" if the server page is open then your device is successfully connected with localhost

Answer (score 0):

USB doesn't provide network to mobile device. If it's connected to your wifi, then hit your laptop address provided by the router. If it's connected to your mobile network, then first find out your router external IP address, then forward some port to that 10.0.2.2:portno and finally you'll be able to see that server from your device.

**Edited:**

```
I use my local ip for that i.e. 192.168.0.1 and it works.
```

and Let me know !

Comment: can you give me some details